# Get the id of a parent tag with a specific class from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to get the id of `<a>` tag, with a specific class, which is a parent (somewhere above in the DOM tree) of a form when I submit the form

```
<div class="article">
                <div class="titre">Mon premier article de blog</div>
                <div class="resume" style="display: none; ">Ceci est le premier article de blog <a id="1" href="#">link</a></div>
               <div class="content">Ceci est effectivement mon premier article de blog 
                        <div class="nb_com">2 commentaires</div>
                           <div class="form">
                             <form method="post" action="">
                                <div class="form_text">
                                   <textarea name="com" id="com" rows="4" cols="122">... </textarea>
                                 </div>
                                 pseudo : <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo"> 
                           mail : <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">  
                                <input type="button" value="Commenter" onclick="enregistre_com(this.form.com.value,this.form.pseudo.value,this.form.mail.value,this.parentNode.innerHTML">  
                            </form>
                   </div>
               </div>
            <div class="comment">
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I click on the button, I want to retrieve the value of the id of `<a>` tag which is in the `<div class="resume">` tag. The javascript or jquery expression will take place instead of `this.parentNode.innerHTML` (it was just test purpose)

Comment: Do you mean "when I click the button" or do you *really* mean "when I submit the form"?

Comment: when I click. The form is submit by Ajax later in the process

Comment: why are you using "onclick" with jquery/javascript??? just give the form an id and run your mechanics through JS

Comment: +1 to @themerlinproject, you should attach a handler, not use an inline `onclick`. You should attach a **`submit`** handler or you'll miss **my** form submits (tab to button, press **space**) - do your AJAX submit, and return `false` or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submit.

Comment: I do  not want my page to be refresh, so I do not use the submit feature form. But, I will try to do it with a JQuery handler after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to go up to the first shared container (*`.article`*) and then use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the `<a>` inside the `.resume` element..

```
$(this).closest('.article').find('.resume a')[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form :button').click(function(){
    var id = $('.resume a').attr('id'); // 
    // the variable id contains the content of the id attribute
});
```

You may want to change the selectors according to your other markup.

Comment: I did not specify that I have other form in my page with other resume tag, but with different id

Answer (score 0):

this will be the id your  tag when the input button is clicked, even with multiple "resume" classes:

```
id = $(this).closest('.article').find('a').attr('id');
```

here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JMEPj/2/

Comment: I did not specify that I have other form in my page with other resume tag, but with different id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which element you're looking for specifically in your example, but you should look into using jQuery's `.parents([selector])` method (see API page [here](http://api.jquery.com/parents/))

Comment: I'd tried, but did not manage to. I will try with the closest selector which I did not know

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input[type=button]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.className').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: The form is generated as a response of an AJAX call. It is not in the html page while first loadinf. I think I have to use the delegated event mecanism to make your code work, but I do not know well this mecanism for now

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it look like

```
    <input type='button' value='Commenter' onClick='enregistre_com(this.form.com.value,this.form.pseudo.value,this.form.mail.value,$(this).closest(\".article\").find(\".resume a\").attr(\"id\"))' />
```

I was in trouble with the " and the ' because all this js form is encapsulated in php source